# Inkscape: how to cut a group?

Tags: inkscape

The question is straightforward: how to cut a group in Inkscape?

**I already know** that Inkscape can only cut **one** path with another, using `ctrl+/`.

However is there any tips to ease the process?
Having a group of 50+ paths, it is really a burdensome task if we have to manually cut them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that I am aware of is to *combine* all the paths in question, cut the result and *break* it *apart* again. However, this way, all your paths end up having the same style and you may have more than objects than initially in the end.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: Since I posted this answer, some extension scripts for multiple path operations have been posted on the inkscape forums: http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=20762
Use these at your own risk; they are provided as an unofficial temporary solution until Inkscape devs work on this feature!

---

This is not a perfect solution, and it does not suit all situations. However it’s the nearest thing to Illustrator’s “divide all objects below” operation that I could find. If anyone knows a better way please share.

A group cannot be divided, as you know. However multiple paths **can be divided if combined**, along with "exclusion" (at the expense of losing individual styles/colour).

1. Select all the paths you wish to divide and go to **Path>Combine**

[image]
[image]

2. Select your combined paths and **Edit>Duplicate**
3. With this duplicate, go to **Path>Break apart**
4. Then go to **Path>Exclusion** to create a path that will divide paths below
   (I've changed this Exclusion layer to a darker blue to make this clearer to follow)

[image]

5. Select all paths *and* this exclusion path then **Path>Divide**

[image]

This should divide all paths from your original shapes.

*Note: Sometimes using exclusion with overlapping shapes can create gaps, and make it unsuitable as a "divide all below method".*

Comment: The link in the Update does not work anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial: https://inkscapetutorials.org/2014/04/22/inkscape-faq-how-do-i-crop-in-inkscape/

It is: Object > Clip > Set